# JTextPane - Position not represented by view

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Can you please tell me whats wrong with this code

```
            int docLength = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
            int lineCount = (docLength == 0) ? 1 : 0;

            try {
                int offset = docLength;
                while (offset > 0) {
                    offset = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, offset) - 1;
                    lineCount++;
                    num += lineCount;
                }
                System.out.println(lineCount);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am getting this error:

> javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Position not represented by
>   view

The error is on this line of code:

```
offset = Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, offset) - 1;
```

Comment: What does Utilities.getRowStart do?

Answer (score 0):

You added a tag saying this question is about a JTextPane, yet you call the variable a `textArea`. Be consistent. If it extremely confusing to simple inconsistencies. The answer can be different depending on whether you are actually using a JTextPane or a JTextArea.

I don't know why you get the error because you didn't post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

If you are attempting to determine the number of lines of text in the text pane then you can use the `getLines()` method found in [Text Utilities](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/).

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if you have e.g. a `HTMLDocument` and the document has `<head>` section. The section has representation in model so there is an `Element` and approriate offset in the document but the `<head>` `Element` has no `View` (visible reprsenation) so it can't find visible line start for the Element's offset